# Identifying chat apps being used via gmail accounts

Tags: gmail, instant-messaging, application

Besides being the MD, I am also the Gmail administrator for a small firm and have concerns as to which chatt apps on the iphones, etc that employees are using linking their gmail accounts for confidential conversations. Can a Gmail administrator identify which chatt app is being used to access a gmail account so that I can see if that is an acceptable app. If you can, how is this done? Thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter _which app_ people use?

Comment: The issue is whether they are secure or if they may create a backdoor for someone to tap into our emails.